# How to mount ISO image in RHEV guest OS?

Tags: mount, iso, rhev

I have a CD/DVD ISO image on the RHEV controller domain. I uploaded the image into the RHEV ISO storage via `rhevm-iso-uploader` and able to boot guest OS from it (i.e. the image is available in the Boot Options of the Virtual Machine settings). How easily can I access this ISO image inside guest OS? Straightforward `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iso is attached to the VM (that should be visible in the UI) then the CD should be available inside the VM using `mount`. One thing that comes to mind - do you actualy have a directory called `/mnt/cdrom/` under `/mnt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to RHEVM, attach ISO to VM and then you'll be able to use `mount` to mount it on filesystem.